# Expand and flatten a ragged nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I know that the topic of flattening a nested list has been covered in great detail before, however I think my task is a bit different and I couldn't find any info.

I am writing a scraper, and as output I get a nested list.  The top level list elements are supposed to become rows for data in spreadsheet form. However, since the nested lists are often of different lengths, I need to expand them before flattening the list.

Here's an example. I have

```
   [ [ "id1", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2]],    ["a", "b", "c"]],
     [ "id2", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b"]],
     [ "id3", [["x", "y"],      [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b", "c", ""]] ]
```

The output I ultimately want is

```
   [[ "id1", "x", "y",  z, 1, 2, "", "a", "b", "c", ""],
    [ "id2", "x", "y",  z, 1, 2,  3, "a", "b",  "", ""],
    [ "id3", "x", "y", "", 1, 2,  3, "a", "b", "c", ""]]
```

However, an intermediate list like this

```
   [ [ "id1", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2, ""]], ["a", "b", "c", ""]],
     [ "id2", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2,  3]], ["a", "b",  "", ""]],
     [ "id3", [["x", "y",  ""], [1, 2,  3]], ["a", "b", "c", ""]] ]
```

which I can then simply flatten would also be fine.

The top-level list elements (rows) are built in every iteration, and appended to the full list. I guess it is easier to transform the full list at the end?

The structure in which elements are nested should be the same, however I cannot be certain of it at this point. I guess I have a problem if the structure where to look like this.

```
   [ [ "id1", [[x, y, z], [1, 2]],             ["a", "b", "c"]],
     [ "id2", [[x, y, z], [1, 2, 3]], ["bla"], ["a", "b"]],
     [ "id3", [[x, y],    [1, 2, 3]],          ["a", "b", "c", ""]] ]
```

which should become

```
   [[ "id1", x, y,  z, 1, 2, "",    "", "a", "b", "c", ""],
    [ "id2", x, y,  z, 1, 2,  3, "bla", "a", "b",  "", ""],
    [ "id3", x, y, "", 1, 2,  3,    "", "a", "b", "c", ""]]
```

Thanks for any comments, and please excuse if this is trivial, I am rather new to Python.

Comment: Please clarify how would you like *blanks* to be represented, since `[x, y,  , 1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c", ""]` doesn't look as a valid Python list - you have to put something after `y` and before `1`. Would you like it to be `None`? But that would conflict with a `""` that you used as a *blank* at the end of the list...

Comment: It is also unclear what are `x`, `y` and `z`. Are they some kind of constants or variables that were defined beforehand?

Comment: Edited it for clarification. Some of the items in the lists are already blanks, and it is perfectly fine to expand the list with blanks. I build the list from elements/lists extracted from the pages.

Comment: How would you deal with your last example? I mean the 2nd row in the data set has 4 elements while the rest have only 3. Should the rest of the rows be padded from the right with blanks?

Comment: Extended the question again. In that case blanks should be inserted, so that the result appears as shown. I aligned the corresponding lists/columns.

Comment: In your last example, how do you know you want to fill up item #1 and item #3 with `""` because of `bla` instead of filling up `["bla"]` to `["bla", "", "", ""]` because of `["a", "b", "c", ""]` in item #3?

Comment: I understand this is a problem. I know from the content which lists correspond together. I guess the second task cannot be done without specific checks regarding length or content of sublists? From a quick check it seems the second case does not occur, but the site is fairly large and I cannot know in advance.

Comment: Edited again to indicate that not all elements in each row are necessary lists at the moment.

Comment: hmm this might be easier if you changed the way you got that output instead of trying to change that output once you got it. especially with the `bla` example, that shit be wack yo.

Comment: Maybe I could investigate the length of all the sublists and then expand all of them to some maximum length? I can always delete empty columns. If the second case occurs, it will be a rare case, and I can deal with it if it comes up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got a simple solution for the "same structure" case, using a recursive generator and the `izip_longest` function from `itertools`. This code is for Python 2, but with a few tweaks (noted in comments) it can be made to work on Python 3:

```
from itertools import izip_longest # in py3, this is renamed zip_longest

def flatten(nested_list):
    return zip(*_flattengen(nested_list)) # in py3, wrap this in list()

def _flattengen(iterable):
    for element in izip_longest(*iterable, fillvalue=""):
        if isinstance(element[0], list):
            for e in _flattengen(element):
                yield e
        else:
            yield element
```

In Python 3.3 it will become even simpler, thanks to [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) which will allow the recursive step, `for e in _flatengen(element): yield e`, to become `yield from _flattengen(element)`.

Comment: This is an elegant and flexible solution, and a great place to use recursion effectively.

Comment: I am testing this at the moment, and it seems to work. I have identified most of the cases where the structure deviates and will take care of them beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no the solution for generic case where the structure is not the same.
For example a normal algorithm would match `["bla"]` with `["a", "b", "c"]`, and the result will be

```
 [  [ "id1", x, y,  z, 1, 2, "",   "a", "b", "c", "",  "",  ""],
    [ "id2", x, y,  z, 1, 2,  3, "bla",  "",  "", "", "a", "b"],
    [ "id3", x, y, "", 1, 2,  3,   "a", "b", "c", "",  "",  ""]]
```

But if you know you will have a number of rows, each starting with an ID an followed by a nested list structure, the algorithm below should work:

```
import itertools

def normalize(l):
    # just hack the first item to have only lists of lists or lists of items
    for sublist in l:
        sublist[0] = [sublist[0]]

    # break the nesting
    def flatten(l):
        for item in l:
            if not isinstance(item, list) or 0 == len([x for x in item if isinstance(x, list)]):
                yield item
            else:
                for subitem in flatten(item):
                    yield subitem

    l = [list(flatten(i)) for i in l]

    # extend all lists to greatest length
    list_lengths = { }
    for i in range(0, len(l[0])):
        for item in l:
            list_lengths[i] = max(len(item[i]), list_lengths.get(i, 0))

    for i in range(0, len(l[0])):
        for item in l:
            item[i] += [''] * (list_lengths[i] - len(item[i]))

    # flatten each row
    return [list(itertools.chain(*sublist)) for sublist in l]

l = [ [ "id1", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2]],    ["a", "b", "c"]],
      [ "id2", [["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b"]],
      [ "id3", [["x", "y"],      [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b", "c", ""]] ]
l = normalize(l)
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursive_pad(l, spacer=""):
    # Make the function never modify it's arguments.
    l = list(l)

    is_list = lambda x: isinstance(x, list)
    are_subelements_lists = map(is_list, l)
    if not any(are_subelements_lists):
        return l

    # Would catch [[], [], "42"]
    if not all(are_subelements_lists) and any(are_subelements_lists):
        raise Exception("Cannot mix lists and non-lists!")

    lengths = map(len, l)
    if max(lengths) == min(lengths):
        #We're already done
        return l
    # Pad it out
    map(lambda x: list_pad(x, spacer, max(lengths)), l)
    return l

def list_pad(l, spacer, pad_to):
    for i in range(len(l), pad_to):
        l.append(spacer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(recursive_pad([[[[["x", "y", "z"], [1, 2]], ["a", "b", "c"]], [[[x, y, z], [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b"]], [[["x", "y"], [1, 2, 3]], ["a", "b", "c", ""]] ]))
```

Edit: Actually, I misread your question. This code solve a slightly different problem

Comment: There's a typo: `lengths = map(len(l))` should probably be `lengths = map(len, l)`

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this should extend the list to a common length? However, when I run it, it does not actually change anything.