# Unpacking n-level nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose, I have a list,

```
[(1,2), (3, 4)].
```

I will print 1 + 2  and  3 + 4 if all elements of the list are tuples.
But if any one of the elements is also a list, then I add 1 to every element of the inner list and every element of that inner list is appended to the parent list. 
eg.

```
list = [(1,2), [(3, 4), (5, 6)]],
```

becomes

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 1), (5, 6, 1)].
```

Again, if the inner list has a list as an element, we repeat the same thing.
eg.

```
[(1,2), [(3, 4), (5, 6), [(7, 8)]]]
```

first becomes

```
[(1,2), [(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8, 1)]]
```

then finally becomes,

```
[(1,2), (3, 4, 1), (5, 6, 1), (7, 8, 1, 1)].
```

How do I do this procedure to such a list, whose nesting level(as in list in a list in a list....) is not known ?

The code I used to generate this list is as follows:

```
def possible_sums(a):
    if a == 2:
        return [(1, 1)]
    list_l = list(((a - 1, 1), ))
    list_l.append(possible_sums(a-1))
    return list_l


print(possible_sums(8))
```

Comment: I think that the additional requirements (detecting tuples vs. lists, modifying the tuples) sufficiently differ this from that duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses nested generators.  We loop through the items of our list, checking their types.  Whenever we see a `list`, we recursively call `flatten` on that list, and add `1` to the end of each output.  If `item` is a tuple, we just yield it.  Then outside `flatten`, we iterate though the generator to build a list.

```
def flattener(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            gen = flattener(item)
            for item in gen:
                yield item + (1,)
        elif isinstance(item, tuple):
            yield item


print(list(flattener([(1,2), [(3, 4), (5, 6), [(7, 8)]], [(5, 6, 7), [(1, 2)]]])))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4, 1), (5, 6, 1), (7, 8, 1, 1), (5, 6, 7, 1), (1, 2, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984386/expand-and-flatten-a-ragged-nested-list

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
nested_lst = [(1,2), [(3, 4), (5, 6), [(7, 8)]] ,(2,3),[(6,7)]] 
output = []

def de_nestify(lst,lvl):

    if len(lst) != 0:
        for item in lst:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                lvl += 1
                de_nestify(item,lvl)
                lvl = 0 #reset nesting lvl

            else:
                item += (1,)*lvl
                output.append(item)


de_nestify(nested_lst,0)

print(output) 
#[(1, 2), (3, 4, 1), (5, 6, 1), (7, 8, 1, 1), (2, 3), (6, 7, 1)]
```